# Why I am not getting the second string s2 on the display?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

In this program I convert a String (user defined type) to a C-string and then I display it. I have derived a class Pstring from the String class that also check whether the string passed by the user does not exceed the size of the String object. If it then only size-1 characters will be copied in the C-string else the whole string will be copied. In this program below s2 string is not displayed, Why?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstring>
 using namespace std;

class String                                // user defined string type
{
    protected:
       enum { SZ = 80 };                    // size of all String objects
       char str[SZ];                        // holds a C-string
   public:
      String()                              // no-argument constructor
      { str[0] = '\0'; }

      String( char s[] )                    // 1-argument constructor
      { strcpy( str, s); }                  // converts C-string to String

      void display() const                  // display the String
      { cout << str ; }

      operator char*()                      // conversion operator
      { return str; }                       // converts String to C-string

  }; 

class Pstring : public String               // class Pstring ( derived publically from String class)
  {
     public:
      Pstring() : String()                  // no-argument constructor
      {     }
      
      Pstring( char s[] );                  // 1-argument constructor declared
 };

 Pstring::Pstring( char s[] )               // 1-argument constructor
   {

        if( strlen(s) > SZ-1 )
         {
            for( int i = 0; i < SZ-1; i++)
                str[i] = s[i];
                
            str[SZ-1] = '\0';
               
         }
         else 
             String(s);
   }

   int main()
  {
      Pstring s1, s2;
       s1 = "My name is Lakhan and your name is Ram Kumar. My age is 35 and your age is 40 
            then how I am your uncle"
           " You are a damn duff who can't understand this small thing that whether a thing is 
           right or wrong";
       s2 = "My name is lakhan and your is what??";

   cout << "\ns1 = "; s1.display();
   cout << "\ns2 = "; s2.display();         // Here is the problem( it is not displayed)

   cout << endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `String(s)` doesn't call the base class constructor, you can only construct the base class via the initialiser list

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: This code causes several compilation errors on MSVC (missing asignment opeator and others). I believe this is not the exact code you used to produce the result you mentioned.

Comment: @wohlstad I want to produce the same result that I have mentioned. But I am not getting it.

Comment: @Quimbly No, I don't know how to use debugger as I am a beginner.

Comment: @Alan Birtles Can you suggest any solution for that part of the code particularly???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the constructor of the parent class `String(s);` but that in itself does not save the content `s` in `str`.

Change it so something like this:

```
Pstring::Pstring(char s[]) { // 1-argument constructor
  if (strlen(s) > SZ - 1) {
    ...
  } else { 
    strcpy(str, s); 
  }
}
```

Comment: `{ strcpy( str, s); }` would do just as well.

Comment: @Johannes Heuel I don't understand how the constructor in base class is not saving the content of s in str!!!

Comment: @NitishKumarMishra You are calling the constructor of the parent class but then do not use the result.

Comment: @Johannes Heuel Then how can I use it without using the solution that you have suggested. going with the my solution.

Comment: @NitishKumarMishra In C++ the constructor of the base class is not usually called explicitly in the body of another constructor. You could move the string copying to another function of the base class and call that function but then you could also use strcpy.